# Typedef redefinition error when trying to build XCode project for release

Tags: xcode, typedef, redefinition, llvm-3.0

I can build my project in Xcode(4.2) for debugging without issues, but when I want to build it for release (build for archiving) I get error:"Typedef redefinition with different types (unsigned int vs unsigned long)".

Problematic code is:

```
#ifdef _LZMA_UINT32_IS_ULONG 
typedef long Int32; 
typedef unsigned long UInt32; 
#else 
typedef int Int32; 
typedef unsigned int UInt32; <--error on this line
#endif
```

You can see whole file on: 
http://read.pudn.com/downloads166/sourcecode/zip/758136/C/Types.h__.htm

Previous definition is in MacTypes.h from CoreServices framework.

I have the same preprocessor macros for Debug and Release, and I am using Apple's LLVM compiler 3.0. Same error happens when I try to build project for analyzing.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I know you think you have the same preprocessing macros everywhere, but can you put  #error fail right inside the ifdef _LZMA_UINT32_IS_ULONG block and make sure that code is never compiled? I feel like different paths through that ifdef are being taken for debug vs release if you confirm that you can start to track why.

Comment: Are you compiling for the same target in debug vs release (i.e. is one of them compiling just for 64 bit and the other compiling for 32 bit or both?

Comment: @DRVic You are right, I was compiling just for 64bit when debugging, and for release I used 32bit/64bit. When I chose only 64bit for release it builds fine. How can I make it compile for both 32bit/64bit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the case where you're getting the error (when compiling 32 bit) you already have the equivalent of

```
typedef unsigned int UInt32; <--error on this line
```

(hence the error) So you can delete the offending line.

Apparently not all of your source includes / imports MacTypes.h, so to have it both ways, surround the offending line with #ifdefs like so:

```
#ifndef __MACTYPES__
typedef unsigned int UInt32;
#endif
```

Unfortunately this is not perfect; you need to be sure that if MacTypes.h is included, it happens before this.  One way to ensure that is to do your system #imports before your local #imports.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing that came on my mind, but if I delete that line I get compiler errors: "Unknown type name UInt32" in other parts of the code.

Comment: So I modified my answer accordingly.  Not entirely pretty.  Been there, though.